# When to quote strings in linux shell commands?

Tags: bash, quoting

i've found some inconsistency with bash commands and I wanted some clarification.

A comment mentioned here said [Also, remember to quote the file pattern ".txt" or the shell will expand it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604468/find-and-delete-txt-files-in-bash]). But then why does the command

```
find . -name *.txt
```

Not obtain an error, it should be expanding the output using a wild card?

Also I found a nice page explaining the [Differences in single quotes and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash),. but then why does using single quotes within a regex not break it?
For example

```
find . -regex '.*x.txt'
```

Why does this work, and not look for the file literally called `.*.txt`

Cheersr

Comment: This is off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: However, note that if the shell wildcard pattern *doesn't* match anything, then it is passed as-is to the application. You need to think carefully about the difference between what s expanded by the shell, and what is handled by the application. Write a little utility that just prints it's arguments and experiment calling it with different things.

Comment: When necessary. Once you know what quoting actually *does*, it's simple to figure out when it is and isn't necessary.

Comment: It can be about programming.  Writing shell scripts is a form of programming.   However, it is very broad.  (Certainly the question in the title is ....)

Answer (score 2):

The shell expands unquoted patterns (where a pattern is a word containing a pattern metacharacter like `*`) before calling the command contained in a command line. In this case, `find . -name *.txt` expands to, perhaps, `find . -name a.txt b.txt c.txt`, in which case only `a.txt` is the argument to the `-name` primary of the `find` command. To prevent this expansion, you quote `*.txt`, because you want that literal string to be the argument.

```
find . -name '*.txt'
```

`find` *itself* uses the pattern to match against each file found while recursing the current directory.

`bash` lets you be somewhat lazy, because if `*.txt` doesn't actually match anything, then it is treated as a literal string by default. There are shell options that change this behavior: `nullglob` causes an unmatched pattern to simply disappear, as if it never existed, and `failglob` causes the shell to raise an error instead. However, it's best to be explicit: if you don't intend a string to undergo pathname expansion, quote it to ensure that it *cannot* be expanded.

Comment: i;m just reading the single vote vs double quote in my link from before. In his example, #11 he says globing doesn't work in quoted strings of any type. Then why does it work in literally every script people write such as '*.txt'?

Comment: @123:  *globbing doesn't work in quoted strings* is correct, **in the shell**.  But `find` is not part of the shell, it is an external program with its own globbing system.  Passing `find` a parameter of `'*.txt'` has to be quoted because it is parsed by the shell *before* the external `find` program is called.  If it was not protected then the shell would leap in and expand it before `find` was even started.

Comment: @cdarke Interesting, how do I differentiate the difference between an internal or external program. Are internals programs just scripts we make ourselves and external programs the one that come precompiled in the os?

Comment: No, internal commands are those that are implemented by the shell itself. Some cannot be implemented as external commands (like `cd`, which changes the state of the shell), while others could be implemented as either (like `test`, which exists as both; the internal version is more efficient because it doesn't require a new process to be forked). The shell's documentation (e.g. the man page) will list the supported built-in internal commands.

Comment: As @chepner says, but a simple way to discover if a command is built-in or external is to use the `type` command.  Try `type cd`, `type echo`, `type ls`, `type find`, `type [[`.  If you get `hashed`, that means it is an external program where the path is cached.